# SQL Server - Merging one record to another and changing items referencing the first item to reference the item it was merged into

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I have a duplicate record in a SQL Server table with (obviously) different unique IDs.

```
 CustomerId FirstName LastName| 
 1          John      Doe     |
 2          John      Doe     |
```

There are child items that are already in the database (let's say an orders table), some relate to one of the items and some relate to the other.

```
OrderId  CustomerId  DateEntered|
100      1           2018/11/01 |
101      2           2018/11/09 |
```

They are both referring to the same customer.
I would like to delete the duplicate record. Is there a way to automatically update the CustomerIds in the Orders table that has a value of 2 to have a value of 1?

Comment: Sample data and expected results as _formatted text_ please not images.

Comment: The short answer is NO... Nothing that would work automatically. You'd have to find all FK references to "CustomerID" (hopefully the database in question actually has good DRI) and generate commands to update their values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a window function to solve this

```
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT T1.*,
       MIN(T1.CustomerId) OVER(PARTITION BY T1.FirstName, T1.LastName ORDER BY T1.CustomerId) RN
FROM T1
)
UPDATE T2
SET T2.CustomerId = CTE.RN
FROM T2 INNER JOIN CTE ON T2.CustomerId = CTE.CustomerId;
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=fe03f7530593931e4915201b693036ad)**

But in the first place you need to fix this, the customer should have one(1) `Unique` id, not multiple IDs.

Comment: Thank you. What I wanted to know was if SQL Server has built in that the records in the other tables that relate to this record can automatically be updated to the record it was merged into without specifically updating the CustomerId in the record in T2.

Comment: It also does happen as sometimes someone adds a customer because he spelled it differently than the one in the database and thinks that it does not exist yet.